# Files under build folder are generated and should not be edited

Tags: android

Whenever a new project is started, the following error comes up

> Files under build folder are generated and should not be edited

and the file `v23/values-v23.xml` is opened.

The previous answers pointed out that changes should be made only to the AndroidManifest file in `app/src` not the other one.

But here the error comes up just as a new project is created.

Comment: Sounds weird. Try reinstalling

Comment: "Rebuild Project" in the "Build" menu usually fixes this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think we faced the same problem:

[image]
[image]

It came out after I update the Android SDK & SDK Tools to version `23`. There must be something changed in the Android SDK & SDK Tools, I changed my `compileSdkVersion` in app/build.gradle from 21 to 23 (you may also need change the version of some other properties):

[image]

then click `Sync Now` (which will be shown after gradle file changed), the error disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem occurred while I've been trying to add Google Map Acivity after putting metadata with the key to other one.

Solution for me was to manually open **app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml** and editing it in the notepad.

Answer (score 1):

Just click on the "Clean Project"(Build > Clean Project).

This might work for you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can delete build folder  of project firstly after clean your project then Rebuild. your problem will be solve.